# C# ASP .NET how to get row gridview when templatefield click?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

i have a problem, i want to get row when i click button in templatefield,
this's my templatefield

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="item-gridview" HeaderStyle-CssClass="text-header-gridview" HeaderText="Infor">
    <ItemTemplate>                  
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-show-detail">Information</button>
    </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

I want to do this because when I click button, I'll retrieve gridview row and pass into modal and show,
So, anyone can help me, how to get row on click button (not asp:Button) in templatefield, or show me a solution how to get row in gridview when button click and show it on modal, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge, ASP.Net grid doesn't have any row click event, or there is but I'm not sure.

Usually to allow user to click on a row to perform something, I prefer to use the `onClientClick` event on the row itself. Something like below:

```
<asp:TemplateField onClientClick="displayModal('<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>')"
ItemStyle-CssClass="item-gridview" HeaderStyle-CssClass="text-header-gridview" HeaderText="Infor">
<ItemTemplate>                  
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-show-detail">Information</button>
</ItemTemplate>
```